# calculating maximal distance for triangle structure problem in Python

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, python-itertools

I wrote a program 5hat outputs the maximum distance that a single possible triangle or a combination of possible triangles can reach away from a wall. It works for all but one case I tried.

I have an input file of the form “3 50 40 30”. A single line of positive integers. The first integer is the number of triangle segments used - in this example “3”. The following integers, sorted in descending order, represent the lengths of the triangle segments. My program outputs the maximum distance that a single possible triangle or a combination of possible triangles can reach away from a wall (there are some requirements on how to construct the triangular structure, e.g. 2 triangles can share one segment, one segment of a triangle must be connected to the corner of another triangle, they can be rotated at any angle and overlap, …, but that’s IMHO secondary here). For the example input the calculated result is “40”.
It works fine for all input I tried, but: “7 42 40 32 30 25 18 15”. The expected result is “66.9495287”; the code below calculates wrongly “39.9482860”.

This is my code:

```
import sys
import itertools
import numpy as np

def max_distance(n, lengths):
    max_dist = 0.0
    permutations = np.array(list(itertools.permutations(lengths)))

    for i in range(len(permutations)):
        perm = permutations[i]
        sides = np.array([perm[i:i+3] for i in range(n-2)])
        valid_triangles = sides[:, 0] < sides[:, 1] + sides[:, 2]
        valid_sides = sides[valid_triangles]

        for side in valid_sides:
            a, b, c = side
            s = (a + b + c) / 2
            area_squared = s * (s - a) * (s - b) * (s - c)

            # Ensure area_squared is positive before calculating height
            if area_squared > 0:
                height = 2 * np.sqrt(area_squared) / a
                max_dist = max(max_dist, height)

    if max_dist.is_integer():
        return str(int(max_dist))
    else:
        return format(max_dist, '.7f')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    input_data = sys.stdin.readline().strip().split()
    n = int(input_data[0])
    lengths = [int(x) for x in input_data[1:]]
   
    result = max_distance(n, lengths)
    print(result)
```

Basically it defines a function *max_distance* that calculates the maximum distance between three points in a given set of lengths. *max_distance* takes two parameters: *n* (the number of lengths) and a list of lengths. It generates all possible permutations of the lengths using *itertools.permutations* and converts them into a NumPy array. It then iterates over each permutation and checks if it forms a valid triangle. For each valid triangle, it calculates the area using Heron’s formula and checks if the area is positive. If the area is positive, it calculates the height of the triangle and updates *max_dist* if necessary. Finally, it checks if *max_dist* is an integer and returns it as a string or in a formatted floating-point representation.

I am aware that this is unoptimised, not beautiful code - I just do not see what’s going wrong here. Any indicators are highly welcome.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why `66.94...` is supposed to be the correct answer? Your code and explanation suggest that `max_dist` is the maximum height you can produce using triangles built from the given side lengths. Intuitively to me, that would happen when the base of the triangle is minimal (`a=15`), and the other two side lengths are as large as possible (`b, c = 42, 40`). With that configuration, `39.948` is indeed correct (I think)! It doesn't make sense to me that you can produce a triangle height larger than any of the side lengths. Note: `66.94... > 42`...

Comment: Side note: are you sure `itertools.permutations` is appropriate? The line `valid_triangles = sides[:, 0] < sides[:, 1] + sides[:, 2]` suggests that column 0 always contains the largest value, but `permutations` produces tuples that are out of order of the original input. Maybe `itertools.combinations(lengths, 3)` is more sensible.

Comment: So: `for a, b, c in itertools.combinations(lengths, 3): ...`. I think the outer loop and the numpy part may be unnecessary in that case ;)

Comment: thanks for commenting - the height can be higher because additional triangles can be “added” to one to create some structure. Similar to building e.g. a bridge based on triangles using sticks of any length. And yes, the “66.xxx” result is given to check.

Comment: I see now, but I can't find the part in your code where you add the heights of multiple triangles together. So how could your code compute that value? :)

Comment: yes, the itertools.permutation operates on descending values starting from column 0. And yes, I know, the outer loop as well as numpy will go :) … but for the moment my brain moves this thing around, and writing and answering here seems to help to reflect.

Comment: Holy Glucose! :) Back to the drawing board! Thanks.